# PHP referer url and redirect

Tags: php

I can't seem to work out why the below sends ALL traffic to the page-not-found page, even if referred by Paypal. Any ideas?

```
$refererUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$Exploded = explode("/",$refererUrl);
$urlToCheck = $Exploded[3];
$findURL = strpos($urlToCheck,'paypal.com');
if($findURL === false){
    header('location:/page-not-found');
} else  {
/* Do something if page referred to by Paypal */
}
```

Comment: Is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` actually set in your server?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is set by the user agent (in your case the browser), and cannot be trusted to have the value you're expecting. I'd recommend you debug the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if `'paypal.com'` is present in `$Exploded[3]`. Why do you expect that part of the referer url to be the hostname? Array indexes start at 0, so counting from left to right would give you the following, indicating that 2 would be the correct index.

```
$Exploded = explode('http://www.google.com/?q=foobar', '/');

// $Exploded now contains:
0: http:
1: 
2: www.google.com
3: ?q=foobar
```

However, it would be more safe to use some utility that will parse arbitrary URLs and read the hostname from the interpreted url. You could do something like this (untested):

```
$referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if($referer['host'] != 'paypal.com')
    header('location:/page-not-found');
else
    /* Do something if page referred to by Paypal */
```

parse_url doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: It says 44 seconds remaining. Will do as soon as clock reaches 0

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the clock system, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `HTTP_REFERER` is set? If you have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) it says

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct?

```
$urlToCheck = $Exploded[3];
```

If your reffer looks like http://www.example.com/....
the by exploding by "/" you will never got domain in 3rd index. It should be 2.

Try using

```
$urlToCheck = $Exploded[2];
```

Comment: Yes, sorry it was meant to be 2, not 3. Working fine now. Cheers!